# Modified Scrollbar with CSS - Chrome works, Safari not

Tags: css

I've got a CSS snippet. It works perfectly in Chrome based Browsers but it doesn't seem to work in Safari. It doesn't need to work in FireFox.

The scrollbar is not shown (or it's full streched). What can I do?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background:  -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(34, 127, 158)), to(rgba(225, 141, 175)));
  background:  linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34, 127, 158) 0%, rgba(225, 141, 175) 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 100000vh #F1F1F1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 100000vh #F1F1F1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100000vh #F1F1F1;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: `-webkit-gradient` is completely obsolete btw - there is no reason to use it in 2021. Stick to `linear-gradient`.

Comment: `100000vh` <-- Why are you doing this?